# Keycloak Get Users returns 403 forbidden

Tags: rest, authentication, keycloak, access-token, keycloak-rest-api

I create token using `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{realm_name}/protocol/openid-connect/token endpoint`.

grant_type=client_credentials
client-id: ------------
client-secret: 78296d38-cc82-4010-a817-65c283484e51

Now I want to get users of realm. Then I send request to `http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/{realm_name}/users?username=demo` endpoint with token.
But I got `403 forbidden` response with `"error": "unknown_error"`. How to solve it?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The service account associated with your client needs to be allowed to view the realm users.

1. Go to http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/{realm_name}/console/#/realms/{realm_name}/clients
2. Select your client (which must be a confidential client)
3. In the settings tab, switch **Service Account Enabled** to **ON**
4. Click on save, the Service Account Roles tab will appear
5. In Client Roles, select **realm_management**
6. Scroll through available roles until you can select **view_users**
7. Click on **Add selected**

You should have something like this :

[image]

You client is now allowed to access users through the REST API.

Comment: Hi. After setting Client Roles,403 Forbidden is resolved.
Thanks.

Comment: Was this changed in Keycloak 17?  The `Service Account Enabled` is not showing on my screen.

Comment: I needed to add `view-users`  role to the user: Users -> <user-name> -> Role Mappings -> Client Roles -> realm-management -> `view-users` -> `[Add Selected >>]`

Comment: @ash to display it you need to set the Access Type of your client to "confidential"

Comment: Lucas's answer didn't help me. only after adding to the user the "view-users" role (as ash suggested) the problem was fixed

Comment: I didn't investigate why, but I added all the roles of realm-management for my case to play ok. Thanks.

Comment: even after adding all roles I'm still getting the 403 error. Any clue? PS. I have Service Account enabled, and it is log in without issues.

Comment: @Kostanos Did you resolve it? I end up into similar issue

Comment: Hey, I did resolve, but I don't remember how. Make sure you that JWT token has roles inside, I think it was the problem, but I don't remember, sorry.

Comment: This article is exactly what I needed, however I had remapped my roles and that interfered with Keycloak recognizing them.
Make sure your roles are in your JWT like:
`"resource_access": {
    "realm-management": {
      "roles": [
        "view-identity-providers",
        "view-realm",
`
This can be done by Client Scopes > Roles > Mappers:
- Client Role = resource_access.${client_id}.roles
- Realm Roles = realm_access.roles

Comment: Thanks, It works fine. also, you can make a group for associated users and then apply those changes on the group.

Comment: Thanks @Kostanos. I was trying to use a JWT without roles. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

**to create(add) user**

send POST request to:

```
http://localhost:8180/admin/realms/YOUR_REALM_NAME/users
```

with this body sample:

```json
{
"firstName":"Amir",
"lastName":"Sharafkar", "email":"amirh.sharafkar@gmail.com", "enabled":"true", 
"username":"sharafkar", 
"credentials":[{
"type":"password",
"value":"1234",
"temporary":false
}]}
```

**to get all users**

send GET request to:

```
http://localhost:8180/admin/realms/YOUR_REALM_NAME/users
```

with "Authorization" key header with value: `Bearer {YOUR_TOKEN}`

**to get individual user**

send GET request to:

```
http://localhost:8180/admin/realms/YOUR_REALM_NAME/users/{id}
```

with "Authorization" key header with value: `Bearer {YOUR_TOKEN}`

**DO NOT FORGET** - Keycloak "version: 20.0.2"

assign role to your client with this steps:

1. Click Assign role button

[image: Click Assign role button]

2. Select Filter by clients

[image: Select Filter by clients]

3. and finally add "manage-users" role to your client

[image: and finally add "manage-users" role to your client]

Comment: Jizz! `2. Select Filter by clients` - that was I was looking for so long today. Thank you! **Why they hide it so deep!?**

Answer (score 5):

You need to assign a target realm-management role for your custom user. E.g. Keycloak version 19.02 to assign any realm-management role such as manage-users, manage-clients or realm-admin, you must follow these steps:

1. create a new user
2. Navigate to user details and open the Role Mapping tab.
3. click the Assign role button
4. select Filter by clients
5. you will see the first 10 results, click ">" to see the next 10 results, etc., or use the search box
6. select one target role

[Filter by client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wegNr.png), [realm-management roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnb2h.png)

Answer (score 2):

- Login to your Keycloak admin console and navigate to the "Client
  Scopes" section.
- Click the "Create" button to create a new client scope “openid“ as
  default.
- then go to your realm client select client scopes tab.
- then add the openid scope.

[image]

Comment: The reason why this worked, is most likely because you were using an example that had `scope=openid` in the URL at some point. This should not be needed in most scenarios unless you explicitly want to divide up scopes.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with the quarkus-Version 18.0.2:

- a client "tmp" identical configured like "admin-cli" (only different name)
- all roles of "realm-management" assigned to the generated service-user
- using a client-credential-Token of "tmp" for the user-Search-Endpoint (/auth/admin/realms/b2c/users/) leads to 403
- using a manually created user works well (password-credential-type)
- using the "admin-cli" client to get the client-credential-Token works well, too

I found this: "client_id is a confidential client that belongs to the realm master" here: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/server_development/topics/admin-rest-api.adoc

**I don't know why this restriction was introduced**, but when you fetch your token from master (/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token), then you are allowed to use a custom client and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

As the response code (`403`) says `forbidden`, it means that server has understood the request but you don't have the permissions to request that API.

So to get the access to view the users/groups/roles which are available in the Keycloak you must have to map the roles to the user. You can follow the below path to map any roles.

CLick on Users --> select your user --> click on Role Mapping --> click on Assign Roles --> Filter by clients --> select the roles and save

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMnhi.png)