# Access to Keycloak admin REST API by admin-cli client only?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to do some request by administration REST API through custom client. Client has proper scopes. I get 403. Same issue when authenticate by user (with proper roles). Everything works fine when I change client to 'admin-cli' and use user authentication. I can not see any difference in configuration.
Is it possible to use admin REST API only through client 'admin-cli' and user authentication?

Answer (score 1):

See this answer to learn how to authorize your client to use the admin rest api : [Keycloak Get Users returns 403 forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66452108/keycloak-get-users-returns-403-forbidden/66454728#66454728)

Comment: I have Service Account Enabled to ON, set proper roles. The only difference is when I use custom client instead of 'admin-cli'